# Output stream locking for multiprocess synchronisation?

Tags: c++, stl, process, stream, locking

Having multiple processes, all writing on the same output stream (e.g. with `std::cout`), is there a way to lock the stream so that, when a process starts writing his own message, it can do it till the end (e.g. with `std::endl`)?

I need a portable way of doing it.

Comment: It might not fit the parameters of your situation, but you could potentially funnel all data to a separate worker process that aggregates the data (with its own internal locking) before dumping them to stdout.

Comment: @reuben: in my case your solution is the best one. If you write an answer I can select it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear if it would fit the parameters of your situation, but you could potentially funnel all data to a separate worker process that aggregates the data (with its own internal locking) before dumping them to stdout.

Answer (score 2):

You are out of luck. You will have to use whatever your taget OS provides. This means using global/system-wide mutexes or `lockf()` like functions. You could use some 3rd party library to satisfy the portability requirement, like [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html).

Comment: Do you know if there is anything like that in C++11?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a UNIX like OS, then you may be able to mimic the behavior you want with a `stringstream` adapter. This may not be the best way to accomplish it, but the idea is to trigger a single `write` call whenever `std::endl` is encountered.

```
// Assume fd is in blocking mode
class fdostream : public std::ostringstream {
    typedef std::ostream & (*manip_t) (std::ostream &);
    struct fdbuf : public std::stringbuf {
        int fd_;
        fdbuf (int fd) : fd_(fd) {}
        int sync () {
            int r = ::write(fd_, str().data(), str().size());
            str(std::string());
            return (r > 0) ? 0 : -1;
        } 
    } buf_;
    std::ostream & os () { return *this; }
public:
    fdostream (int fd) : buf_(fd) { os().rdbuf(&buf_); }
};

fdostream my_cout(1);
my_cout << "Hello," << " world!" << std::endl;
```

This should achieve the effect of synchronized writes, at the cost of buffering input into a `stringstream` and then clearing the internal `string` after each flush.

For greater portability, you could modify the code to use `fwrite`, and specify unbuffered writes with `setvbuf`. But, the atomicity of `fwrite` would depend on the C implementation of the library function.